# phantomJS - scrape content inside table

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, scrape

I'm using phantomJS to scrape a page. The script is called by a php function which I've added at the end. I've added a mockup of the HTML code as well.

The script waits for a table with class `main-table-redesign` to load.

After the div is table is loaded, I need to get the content in that specific table. I am not sure how to do this part. I can get the contents of the entire page by doing `page.content` but I think this greatly increases the time for the operation to complete.

```js
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(pageURL, function (status) {
    // Check for page load success
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to access network");
    } else {    
    
        waitFor(function() {
            // Check in the page if a specific element is now visible
            return page.evaluate(function() {
                return !!document.querySelector(".main-table-redesign");
            });
        }, function() {

            //TODO
            //return table.main-table.redesign content
            
           phantom.exit();
        });
    }
    
});
```

I tried this in the todo part just to see if I can get the document title:

```
        var title = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.title;
        }
        console.log(title);
```

But when I do this, the script just keeps running. I understand that this is due to evaluate being sandboxed. So then how can I return the contents (with tags) of the table only?

Below is the PHP code which calls the script, although this isn't needed here.

```
<?php

$content = execute("waitfor.js");

var_dump($content);


function execute($script, $args = array(), $options = array(), $bin = 'phantomjs', $debug = true) {

    $option_str = '';
    foreach ($options as $option => $value)
    {
        $option_str .= '--'.$option.'='.$value.' ';
    }

    // Escape
    $cmd = escapeshellcmd("{$bin} {$option_str}{$script} " . implode(' ', $args));
    if($debug) $cmd .= ' 2>&1';
    // Execute
    $result = shell_exec($cmd);
    if($debug) return $result;
    if($result === null) return false;

    // Return
    if(substr($result, 0, 1) !== '{') return $result; // not JSON
    $json = json_decode($result, $as_array = true);
    if($json === null) return false;
    return $json;

}
```

The HTML code is humongous, even the part that I need scraped. So I'm just gonna add what it looks like.
HTML mockup:

```
<body>
    <div class='table-content'>
        <table class="main-table-redesign" id="main-table" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="table-data-row>
                <td class="table-data-cell-bar">A1</td>
                <td class="table-data-cell-bar">A2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="table-data-row>
                <td class="table-data-cell-bar">B1</td>
                <td class="table-data-cell-bar">B2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Really appreciate if someone can clarify why this isn't working and what I can do to make it work.

Comment: Can you add the html as well ?

Comment: Added a mockup of the HTML part that I need scraped, since the actual HTML is massive.

Comment: `the script just keeps running` Either `.main-table-redesign` never appears or you have a syntax error in your code. The latter causes PhantomJS v2.1 to hang silently. Try v1.9.8, try making a screenshot to make sure PhantomJS sees the same page you do (and not mobile version perhaps).

Comment: No I'm sure PJS sees the same page. Because when I do a console.log(page.content) I see the ".main-table-redesign" table. I just think I'm not doing the .evaluate properly. I'm not sure what to fix there.